# Obtain google shopping matches

Tags: api, google-shopping-api, google-shopping

So, as the title says, I would like to emulate the behaviour of the google shopping tab.

For example, whenever I search for "Samsung A50" I get different shopping results from different merchants.

Is there a way in the whole google shopping API to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content API is for submitting data to Google Merchant Center.

Currently, there is no official Google API for returning results of shopping ads. You may want to use a tool such as semrush.

Comment: That's a shame.
Thanks for the answer anyways!

Answer (score 0):

For scraping Google Shopping you can use third party API like [Google Shopping API](https://serpapi.com/google-shopping-api) from SerpApi (paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend).

Check code in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-shopping-serpapi#main.py).

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import json

params = { 
  "engine": "google_shopping",                  # search engine. Google, Bing, Yahoo, Naver, Baidu...
  "q": "Samsung A50",                           # query
  "location": "Austin, Texas, United States",   # where you want the search to originate
  "hl": "en",                                   # language
  "gl": "us",                                   # country of the search, US -> USA
  "api_key": "..."                              # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key
}

all_titles = []

search = GoogleSearch(params)                   # where data extraction happens on the backend
results = search.get_dict()                     # JSON -> Python dict

for result in results["inline_shopping_results"]:
    all_titles.append({"title": result.get("title")})

print(json.dumps(all_titles, indent=2))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Samsung Galaxy A50 US Version Factory Unlocked Cell Phone with 64GB Memory, 6.4\" Screen, Black, [SM-A505UZKNXAA]"
  },
  {
    "title": "Galaxy A50 64GB Black Unlocked GSM"
  },
  {
    "title": "Samsung Samsung Galaxy A53 5G - Amazing Black - 128GB (with 24 monthly payments) - Samsung Galaxy Phone"
  },
  {
    "title": "Samsung Galaxy A23 5G - Black - 64GB (with 24 monthly payments) - Samsung Galaxy Phone"
  },
  other results ...
]
```

There's a [Google Shopping](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=google_shopping&q=Coffee) playground if you want to see what else can be extracted using API.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.